# Fallback intent not providing fulfillment text for web integration

Tags: java, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm using Java to integrate my agent with my website. The problem that I'm facing is that dialogflow is replying with a null string when the Default Fallback intent is triggered although I have provided the text response in the fallback intent. I have gone further to check the isFallback boolean in my code but it gives me a false value even when the fallback intent is triggered. This is the Raw interaction log from the history section of the agent which shows the value of isFallback boolean to be true!

```
 {
  "queryText": "I want to provide a feedback",
  "action": "input.fallback",
  "fulfillmentText": "Sorry, I didn't get you! Do you have any other question?",
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "text": {
        "text": [
          "[{\"type\":0,\"speech\":\"Sorry, I didn't get you! Do you have any other question?\"}]"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "intent": {
    "id": "af1f6c3e-d637-448a-bb4e-760a5e4be6f2",
    "displayName": "Fallback",
    "isFallback": true
  },
  "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
  "languageCode": "en"
}
```

Here is the Java code to check and print the query result!

```
try(SessionsClient sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create()) {

    SessionName session = SessionName.of(projectId, sessionId);

    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(inputText)) {
        Builder textInput = TextInput.newBuilder().setText(inputText).setLanguageCode(languageCode);
        // Build the query with the TextInput
        QueryInput queryInput = QueryInput.newBuilder().setText(textInput).build();
        DetectIntentResponse response = sessionsClient.detectIntent(session, queryInput);
        QueryResult queryResult = response.getQueryResult();
        Boolean fallbackFind = queryResult.getIntent().getIsFallback();
        System.out.format("Fulfillment Text: '%s'\n", queryResult.getFulfillmentText());
        System.out.println(fallbackFind);
      }
}
```

The output of this code is as follows:

```
Query Text: 'I want to provide a feedback'
Detected Intent: Default Fallback Intent (confidence: 1.000000)
Fulfillment Text: ''
false
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of your Java code?

Comment: Did you define a response text for default fallback intent in Dialogflow console? If the text inside of Responses field is non-empty, then you should be getting a text response back, unless you forgot to press "Save" button.

Comment: I've provided a response text and when I try it from test console of Dialogflow I get the response over there! I have updated the Raw Interaction log in the question. It has the text value in it along with the boolean isFallback being true! But it gives me an empty string and false value while calling it from my code.

Comment: Can you update answer with the code for methods you're calling in the Java code you provided, specifically - ```response.getQueryResult```?

Comment: I have done that. I still don't understand why the Raw interaction log is showing isFallback as true but the system is giving an output of false.